# find the sum of parent-child in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, parent-child, recursive-query

```
id  parent-id   total
139    0       -11000.00
140   139      -2000.00
141   140      3000.00
142   141       0.00
143   142      5000.00
144   143      0.00
145   144      0.00
147   145      0.00
148   147      0.00
```

This is my table. the values is stored in temporary table.I need find the parent child sum.
expected output

```
id  parent-id   total        sub-tot
139        0    -11000.00   -5000
140      139    -2000.00    6000
141      140    3000.00    8000
142      141    0.00       5000
143      142    5000.00    5000
144      143    0.00       0
145      144    0.00       0
147      145    0.00       0
148      147    0.00       0
```

i couldn't use recursive as my data is present in temp table. is there any other way

Comment: How does this "sum of parent-child" work?

Comment: i have given the expected output for eg id-139 sub-tot should be(-11000-2000+3000+0+5000+0+0+0+0).@KIKOSoftware and similar for sub child, i have given the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

> i couldn't use recursive as my data is present in temp table.

You may use static table copy in stored procedure, for example.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_subtotal ()
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE statictest SELECT * FROM temptest;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                parent_id, 
                total, 
                0 subtotal, 
                id current_id, 
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                             FROM statictest tt2 
                             WHERE tt2.parent_id = statictest.id ) done
         FROM statictest
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.id, 
                cte.parent_id, 
                cte.total, 
                cte.subtotal + tt1.total, 
                tt1.id,
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                             FROM statictest tt2 
                             WHERE tt2.parent_id = tt1.id )
         FROM cte 
         JOIN statictest tt1 ON cte.current_id = tt1.parent_id )
SELECT id, parent_id, total, subtotal 
FROM cte
WHERE done
ORDER BY id;

DROP TABLE statictest;

END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8667bfeb06495f6f4dea7280b27a2a43

Comment: thanks mate the result is not summing the parent level amount

Comment: @yeshwant If you need something another then use your own query... my answer primarily tells how you may solve the problem with temporary table...

Comment: @akia yes i trying to understand from your query and solving it. thanks mate